# How to Create a Timed Session on Android Using Best Practices?

Tags: android, session, sharedpreferences

I've scenario where I want to make sure that the User who logged into the App is the real themselves. The reason why i want to do this is because my current app can't logged the User out from the App, which is causing the lack of the ID authenticity.

In order to achieve that, I think I have a few option by using timed session to make sure the ID is genuine:

1. Create a timed session by triggering some background function or
   something, so when the User reach the time limit then the App will automatically logged out the User. (*But I don't know if its good to run some background process this long*)
2. Create a timed session by storing some datetime value into server at the log in page and some checker method that will be placed at `onResume()` method (or something), so when the time that stored in server *minus* the current time, then the App will log out the User.

I don't know which one is the best it was all come from my mind. I've been trying to do some research but the closest case that may help me is on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qc9CeaGYYuc). The rest is just explaining the basic usage of Shared Preferences, which I already know before

Answer (score 0):

i think a solution might be more approachable if you could explain a bit more this statement : "which is causing the lack of ID authenticity."

if your API response is returning 300> code to indicate some kind of 
invalid credentials . then you can intercept that using your networking API 
see :[auth interceptor](https://medium.com/@tsaha.cse/advanced-retrofit2-part-2-authorization-handling-ea1431cb86be%20auth). and go from there .

Comment: Alright i'll explain it, the statement "_which is causing the lack of ID authenticity_", means let's say you have only 3 user log in account and give it to the department who need it. These 3 people currently are logged in into the app and everytime they do something, the app record their ID as a person in charge(PIC). But in my case, some people are lending these ID to many people and use it many times with the same ID, which is made me don't know who the real PIC is. So if I apply this method, I hope the User are forced to re enter the password if I changed it from the server. Is it clear?

Comment: a quick solution is to gently ask users not to do so, but we both know that won't work. 

you need to use an auth token generated by the server at first interaction, this token takes as input besides user_id, the UDID of the device (and any other important metadata like OS ). any other user trying to enter with someone's else id, will have a conflict in using a diff UDID than previously registered. 
this way ull ensures the uniqueness of the session.

Comment: Ohh let me ensure my understanding, so after the first sign in process I have to save some unique data from someone device (like OS information, etc (eventhough I still don't know yet)) and include it on post validation process in the end? So if the 2nd user who want to use this ID, he won't succeed because the unique ID posted aren't the same compared to the unique ID that have been stored before by the 1st User. Is my understanding is true?